# Partially pre-compile code (or maybe use .so library) while leaving another part of code open to edits

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, precompile

I'm trying to do a somewhat odd thing that realistically I'm not sure is even possible with current constraints but is outside of my scope of knowledge so it could be. I'll hopefully be able to make everything clear enough in the question, but it will be a little broad in scope, its too big to get detailed.

Anyway, I have a C codebase (we'll call it bar) that is rather large and takes a bit of time to compile. Not a huge deal normally, but now there is a set of files that are changed often and currently the changes can only be confirmed as good after running a compile. Due to the nature of how these are changed it could result in people running multiple compiles in a day, taking quite a lot of time.

What I want to do on a broad scale is only have to actually compile the set of files that might change (about 20, all in 1 directory, we'll call it foo) and have everything else (bar and everything under it except for foo) ready before hand. Initially was looking at .so library for the task, but not positive anymore that's correct. Either way, it still seemed likely to be reasonably possible until I realized that some of the files in directory foo were included by other files in bar. Mostly the files in foo only include files and are kind of the end point, not being included in things. But with a few of them being included I'm not sure what can be done.

My two thoughts are generate a .so library of everything outside of foo that somehow still checks on the needed included files at compile time, or get some kind of general pre-compile set up. Neither of these seem like they would work at a glance, but I very well could be wrong.

A third option, less ideal but better then nothing, is to generate the .so library with everything including any files in foo that are needed at that point, just leaving out the files that aren't included anywhere. It seems like this would work better, though even if it would I'm still not really sure how to go about it.

So basically, is there a way to do what I want to some extent, and if so what is the best method?

Sorry about the broadness of the question, the codebase is too large to provide lots of detail. I will try to edit and add in any information that people think is needed though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Doesn't *any* sensible build system already have as a core feature that it only rebuilds things that have changed?

Comment: If your only concern is *build time*, shared libraries won't shorten that over static ones provided that you have a proper build system that only compiles stuff *that has actually changed*